# Write Allocate / Fetch on Write Cache Policy

Tags: caching, computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I couldn't find a source that explains how the policy works in great detail. The combinations of write policies are explained in [Jouppi's Paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-91-12.pdf) for the interested. This is how I understood it.

1. A write request is sent from cpu to cache.
2. Request results in a cache-miss.
3. A cache block is allocated for this request in cache.(Write-Allocate)
4. Write request block is fetched from lower memory to the allocated cache block.(Fetch-on-Write)
5. Now we are able to write onto allocated and updated by fetch cache block.

Question is what happens between step 4 and step 5. (Lets say Cache is a non-blocking cache using Miss Status Handling Registers.)

Does CPU have to **retry write request on cache until write-hit** happens? (after fetching the block to the allocated cache block)

If not, where does **write request data is being held** in the meantime?

Edit: I think I've found my answer in [Implementation of Write Allocate in the K86™ Processors](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/AMD/All%20CPU/21326F.pdf) . It is directly being written into the allocated cache block and it gets merged with the read request later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is directly being written into the allocated cache block and it gets merged with the read request later on.

No, that's not what AMD's pdf says.  They say the store-data is merged with the just-fetched data from memory and *then* stored into the L1 cache's data array.

Cache tracks validity with cache-line granularity.  There's no way for it to store the fact that "bytes 3 to 6 are valid; keep them when data arrives from memory".  That kind of logic is too big to replicate in each line of the cache array.

Also note that the pdf you found describes some specific behaviour of their AMD's K6 microarchitectures, which was single-core only, and some models only had a single level of cache, so no cache-coherency protocol was even necessary.  They do describe the K6-III (model 9) using MESI between L1 and L2 caches.

---

A CPU writing to cache has to hold onto the data until the cache is ready to accept it.  It's not a retry-until-success process, though.  It's more like the cache notified the store hardware when it's ready to accept that store (i.e. it has that line active, and in the Modified state if the cache is coherent with other caches using the [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol)).

In a real CPU, [multiple outstanding misses can be in flight at once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss) (even without full out-of-order speculative execution).  This is called miss under miss.  The CPU<->cache connection needs a buffer for each outstanding miss that can be supported in parallel, to hold the store data.  e.g. a core might have 8 buffers and support 8 outstanding load or store misses.  A 9th memory operation couldn't start to happen until one of the 8 buffers became available.  Until then, data would have to stay in the CPU's store queue.

These buffers might be shared between loads and stores, or there might be dedicated **store buffers**.  The OP reports that searching on **store buffer** found lots of related stuff of interest; one example being [this part of Wikipedia's MESI article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Memory_Barriers).

The L1 cache is really a part of a CPU core in modern high-performance designs.  It's very tightly integrated with the memory-order logic, and needs to be able to efficiently support atomic operations like `lock inc [mem]` and lots of other complications (like memory reordering).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_disambiguation#Avoiding_WAR_and_WAW_dependencies for example.

Some other terms:

- store buffer
- store queue
- memory order buffer
- cache write port / cache read port / cache port
- globally visible

---

distantly related: [An interesting post](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/) investigating the adaptive replacement policy of Intel IvyBridge's L3 cache, making it more resistant against evicting valuable data when scanning a huge array.

Comment: May I learn the name of buffer which holds store data? I know CPU can have multiple outstanding read requests because of miss status handling registers which makes it a non-blocking cache, but I don't know the name of hardware which acts as a buffer for store data that is expected to be merged with fetched data from lower memory in AMD K6 case. I would appreciate it if you share me the name or details or examples of this hardware.

Comment: @menderft: "Store buffer" apparently includes this meaning.  The MESI article on Wikipedia [uses that term when describing cache-miss stores having to wait while writing to an invalid cache line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Memory_Barriers).  On an architecture with strong memory ordering, a CPU would need to coordinate things to make sure stores didn't commit in an order that wasn't architecturally allowed.  It also needs to snoop store buffers for its own loads, to maintain the appearance of in-order execution of a single thread.  So the buffers are part of the store queue.

Comment: Yes, there are many question related to my question when I search for store buffer. Thanks.