# is a concurent write and read to a non-atomic variable of fundamental type without using it undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, concurrency, race-condition, lock-free, stdatomic

in a lock-free queue.pop(), I read a trivialy_copyable variable (of integral type) after synchronization with an atomic aquire inside a loop.
Minimized pseudo code:

```
//somewhere else writePosition.store(...,release)

bool pop(size_t & returnValue){
writePosition = writePosition.load(aquire)
oldReadPosition = readPosition.load(relaxed)
size_t value{};
do{
  value = data[oldReadPosition]
  newReadPosition = oldReadPosition+1
}while(readPosition.compare_exchange(oldReadPosition, newReadPosition, relaxed)
// here we are owner of the value
returnValue = value;
return true;
}
```

the memory of `data[oldReadPosition]` can only be changed iff this value was read from another thread bevor.

read and write Positions are ABA safe.
with a simple copy, `value = data[oldReadPosition]` the memory of `data[oldReadPosition]` will not be changed.

but a write thread `queue.push(...)` can change `data[oldReadPosition]` while reading, iff another thread has already read oldPosition and changed the readPosition.

it would be a race condition, if you use the value, but is it also a race condition, and thus undefined behavior, when we leave `value` untouched? the standard is not spezific enough or I don´t understand it.
imo, this should be possible, because it has no effect.
I would be very happy to get an qualified answer to get deeper insights

thanks a lot

Comment: Yes.   It is the concurrent (indeterminately sequenced) reading and writing of `data[oldReadPosition]` that causes undefined behaviour.   The variable that `data[oldReadPosition]` is assigned by value to (i.e. `value`) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's UB in ISO C++; `value = data[oldReadPosition]` in the C++ abstract machine involves reading the value of that object.  (Usually that means lvalue to rvalue conversion, IIRC.)

But it's mostly harmless, probably only going to be a problem on machines with hardware race detection (not normal mainstream CPUs, but possibly on C implementations like clang with threadsanitizer).

**Another use-case for non-atomic read and then checking for possible tearing is the SeqLock**, where readers can prove no tearing by reading the same value from an atomic counter before and after the non-atomic read.  It's UB in C++, even with `volatile` for the non-atomic data, although that may be helpful in making sure the compiler-generated asm is safe. (With memory barriers and current handling of atomics by existing compilers, even non-volatile makes working asm).  See [Optimal way to pass a few variables between 2 threads pinning different CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906576/optimal-way-to-pass-a-few-variables-between-2-threads-pinning-different-cpus)

`atomic_thread_fence` is still necessary for a SeqLock to be safe, and some of the necessary ordering of atomic loads wrt. non-atomic may be an implementation detail if it can't sync with something and create a happens-before.

People do use Seq Locks in real life, depending on the fact that real-life compilers de-facto define a bit more behaviour than ISO C++.  Or another way to put it is that happen to work for now; if you're careful about what code you put around the non-atomic read it's unlikely for a compiler to be able to do anything problematic.

But you're definitely venturing out past the safe area of guaranteed behaviour, and probably need to understand how C++ compiles to asm, and how asm works on the target platforms you care about; see also [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/) on LWN; it's aimed at Linux kernel code, which is the main user of hand-rolled atomics and stuff like that.

Comment: thank you very much, this clarifies our discussion a lot and also thank you for the links :-)